# How to integrate Dynamic CRM account and contact list with Sharepoint List without using third party software

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, sharepoint-online

Here is the image of CRM Accounts 
[image]

This is the sharepoint list with all the accounts details data
[image]

Comment: I don't think you're going to get an answer with your question in its current format. Please provide **`(a)`** more information on what you're trying to do **`(b)`** what have you tried so far & include sample code **`(c)`** what is not working

Comment: I am trying use this  [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/girishr/2013/05/13/connecting-sharepoint-online-and-crm-online-using-bcs-2013-edition/) to get my answer